# SQL Server connection over ip and port on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows, firewall, sql-server-2014-express

I have a SQL Server 2014 instance `SQLExpress` installed on Windows 10 Pro, when I open SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to query my database `Banners` and everything is OK.

But when I try to connect to this database using ip address and port (so I could access it from my laravel backend), it says connection time out.

I already specified a port (50000) for the SQL Server service port and added that port to the Windows Firewall inbound rules.

But still no luck.

I tried to check if the port 50000 is open using:
https://portchecker.co

but it says: CLOSED

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 50000 port in your PC is blocked by a naughty process, so I suggest you could check and try to `kill` it. Steps are as followed:

1. press `win+R` to open the cmd window;
2. input command: `netstat -aon|findstr "50000"`;
3. if your 50000 port is really blocked by something, you will find one pid in
   50000 port, and now call this pid `xxx`;
4. input command: `taskkill /pid xxx -t -f`, kill it!
5. then you can connect to your db normally.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1415]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -aon|findstr "50000"

C:\Windows\system32>

it looks like the port is not blocked by windows, 
I also tried many ports , same result